# Can I get malware just by navigating to a webpage?

Tags: malware, web-browser

Is going to a webpage a risk per se? If yes, how does work, and how can we defend ourselves from this? I have to constantly review websites and I get the links from job seekers (that is, I'd navigate to lots of pages, not necessarily from people that I know anything about). Disabling javascript is not an option.

Comment: You ask an important, general question and even use plural form: "how can we defend ourselves from this?" And then abruptly turn it into a call for proposals to fit your particular needs: "Disabling javascript is not an option." Can you decide on one or other?

Answer (score 3):

Since browsers and plugins like flash are not bug-free there is a non-zero risk that you can be attacked with malware just by visiting a web site or that your credentials gets stolen. These can be silent attacks (drive-by-downloads, cross-site-scripting, CSRF...) or social attacks (downloads of fake software updates, scareware, fake login,...). You will find these attacks everywhere, i.e. in your mail, in advertisements (malvertisement) and in compromised systems. These attacks are no longer restricted to the shady sites of the internet.

There is no way to eliminate the risk fully but you can reduce it in several ways:

- Use a  browser with a good security record (i.e. fast fixes, good sandbox...). This is Chrome/Chromium in my personal opinion.
- If possible use a secure OS which gets not targeted much, i.e. Linux. If you only do Web and Mail it will provide everything which Windows can do, only in a more secure environment.
- Install a proper antivirus product if this is needed on your OS. This often does not help against the latest attacks but vendors try to quickly catch up. Don't take the one with the best marketing but look at independent tests.
- Installing ad-blocking software which helps to reduce the risk of [malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising)
- Throw away plugins with a known bad security record, i.e. Flash, Silverlight and Java. Actually you don't need to use any Plugins today.
- Keep your system lean and up-to-date. Throw away any software you don't need and don't install unknown software. Keep all installed software up-to-date. If it is out of support (i.e. old office versions) throw it away.
- Get a router with a good security record. Lots have really bad security and can be easily used for man in the middle attacks.
- Think twice before entering your login credentials anywhere.
- Do sensitive things like online-banking on a dedicated system or at least another browser profile.
- and there is probably more

Comment: Nice list! I would add this: When you have reasons to be suspicious about a link, or for some reason need to use plugins for a site, do so from a VM.

Comment: And here we have a nice, canonical answer lacking an obvious "disable JavaScript" advice because it was excluded it question...

Comment: @techraf: unfortunately disabling Javascript does not help much compared to the rest and makes lots of sites unusable. Browsers have hidden the feature for a while and you need NoScript or similar to get it back. And while I use NoScript  I don't think it is usable for the average user asking here. So just put it under "..and there is probably more" because there are definitely much more things one can do but which are not in the reach of the average user.

Answer (score 1):

Going to web-pages can be dangerous. The most immediate danger is getting your browser hooked. These hooks act as anchors in your browser and allow the attacker to have some basic control over your browser. This can lead to further exploitation and, if the attacker plays it right, can end in you getting owned.

If disabling JavaScript entirely isn't an option, could you put restrictions in place so that JavaScripts must ask to execute?

If you want to see some examples, do some research on a tool called BeEF (Browser Exploitation Framework). Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Do you have any sources for the information you provided?  What does "end in you getting owned" mean?

Comment: You're system could be breached of the attacker plays their cards right.

Comment: How?  More information required here.

Comment: Since they have control over your browser, they can do what they want with it. Exploit vulnerable plugins (Adobe flash for example), or they could redirect you to a site that serves malware. Getting hooked can be a gateway to a much larger attack.